# PHP descending for function

Tags: php, for-loop

I would like to put descending results of "for" function.
**Example:** I have this PHP code:

```
<?php
$field[1] = "Field 1"; // 1
$field[2] = "Field 2"; // 2
$field[3] = "Field 3"; // 3
$field[4] = "Field 4"; // 4
$field[5] = "Field 5"; // 5
$field[6] = "Field 6"; // 6
$field[7] = "Field 7"; // 7
$field[8] = "Field 8"; // 8
$field[9] = "Field 9"; // 9
$field[10] = "Field 10"; // 10

$i = "10";

for ($n=1 ; $n < $i ; $n++ ) {

echo $field[$n];

}
?>
```

Will display:

```
Field 1
Field 2
Field 3
Field 4
Field 5
Field 6
Field 7
Field 8
Field 9
Field 10
```

**How can I do to display descending? Like this:**

```
Field 10
Field 9
Field 8
Field 7
Field 6
Field 5
Field 4
Field 3
Field 2
Field 1
```

Any solution? **Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foreach(array_reverse(range(1, 10), TRUE) as $key => $value)
{
  echo 'Field ' . $value;
}
```

Start from 0.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use for loops to iterate over arrays. PHP has a lovely [foreach](http://php.net/foreach) construct that does this so much better and is way more convenient.

```
foreach (array_reverse($field) as $value) {
    echo "$value\n";
}
```

Comment: I agree, but there are times you have to limit a for loop. For instance, display the last 10 articles on a blog of an array that consists of more. Foreach then kinda sucks since you have to predefine an iterator and up it every loop and watch it till it hits 10 and break it.

Comment: That's not true at all. If you wanted the last times items of an array you'd simply loop over the last 10 items in the array `foreach(array_slice($field, -10) as $value) { echo $value; }`

Comment: Yeah, nice. But that's pass by value, so performance wise maybe not the best.

Comment: It's not pass by anything. It's creating an entirely new array. If you only wanted to iterate over 10 items you would only create an array of the 10 items you wanted in the first place. In either case this is on a tangent from the OP's original question.

Answer (score 3):

```
for ($n=$i; $n>=1; $n--) {
    echo $field[$n];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up `array_reverse` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

I agree with GoogleGuy, you should also change your for statement to foreach

```
<?php
$field[1] = "Field 1"; // 1
$field[2] = "Field 2"; // 2
$field[3] = "Field 3"; // 3
$field[4] = "Field 4"; // 4
$field[5] = "Field 5"; // 5
$field[6] = "Field 6"; // 6
$field[7] = "Field 7"; // 7
$field[8] = "Field 8"; // 8
$field[9] = "Field 9"; // 9
$field[10] = "Field 10"; // 10

$reversed = array_reverse($field); 

foreach ( $reversed AS $element )

 echo $element;

}
?>
```

Comment: This code still won't work. array_reverse is non-destructive. It returns a new array. It does not modify the original array. No need to simply change your answer to mine after you've already answered it.

Comment: I wasn't the guy who downvoted you, but your solution has a mistake, `array_reverse($field)` returns the reversed array so you need put the  returned values into a new array. `$reversed = array_reverse($field)`